# Need to Build a Query with Dynamically genarated OR argument values in MySQL 5.7.30

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am using MySQL version 5.7.30.
I want to create procedure which will generate this Query to the MySQL DATABASE `SELECT * FROM stories WHERE stories.user_id = 67 OR stories.user_id = 68 OR stories.user_id = 71 OR stories.user_id  = 55 OR stories.user_id = 56` Dynamically.

IN the procedure below for a certain type of input value of variable "following" is 67,68,71,55,56 as a string. and value of variable "count_csv" is 5.

From the comma separated value of following I want to generate this query dynamically `SELECT * FROM stories WHERE stories.user_id = 67 OR stories.user_id = 68 OR stories.user_id = 71 OR stories.user_id  = 55 OR stories.user_id = 56`

Please help me. I am novice in MySql.

```
DELIMITER $$
     CREATE PROCEDURE auto_newsfeed(
IN

userid BIGINT)

BEGIN
    DECLARE following VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE count_csv INT;
    DECLARE x INT;
    SET  x = 0;



   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) INTO following
   FROM followers WHERE follower_id = userid;

  


  SELECT LENGTH(following) - LENGTH(REPLACE(following, ',', '')) + 1 INTO count_csv;

    SELECT * FROM stories WHERE user_id = (or_adder : LOOP
        IF X >= count_csv
        THEN
        LEAVE or_adder;
        END IF;

        SET x = x +1;

        
END LOOP;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question, however I would recommend to build something like `SELECT * FROM stories WHERE stories.user_id IN (67,68,71,55,56)`

Comment: ``` SELECT * FROM stories WHERE stories.user_id IN (67,68,71,55,56) ``` Yeah It works. How can I insert the valuues of variable "following"  After WHERE stories.user_id IN ?. Pls help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like all you are trying to do is:

```
select stories.*
from followers
join stories on stories.user_id=followers.user_id
where followers.follower_id=?
```

I don't see any need for a stored procedure or dynamically generated sql here.